# Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.5

I have typescript 1.5.3 and visual studio 2015.

I'm using external modules in my typescript, but it will not build due to the following error:
"Build: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided."

Typescript settings:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|Any CPU'">
<TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
<TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
<TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
<TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
<TypeScriptOutFile />
<TypeScriptOutDir />
<TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
<TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
<TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
<TypeScriptMapRoot />
<TypeScriptSourceRoot />
```

Module:

```
export class Functions {
errorHelper(xhr: any, errorType: any, exception?: any) {
    var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText;
    alert(`Account lookup failed. ${errorMessage}`);
}

getParameterByName(name: string) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp(`[\?&]${name}=([^&#]*)`);
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937225/how-to-provide-the-module-flag-in-a-vs2015-project/31945447#31945447) on Stackoverflow. There's a bug in VS2015 RTM. You have to edit csproj file in order to fix that issue.

> To fix:
>
> 1. Right-click the project, unload it, then right click again and edit it.
> 2. Search for `<TypeScriptModuleKind>`, and then locate the parent element, which should be called `<PropertyGroup>`.
> 3. Look for the text "`Any CPU`" in the `Condition` attribute value, change it to "`AnyCPU`" -- i.e. remove the space.
> 4. Search again and repeat the change in case you have TypeScript settings for other build conditions.

Comment: That worked. You are awesome! Thank you.