# How to fix "cannot compile modules unless the --module flag is provided" in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

according to this [Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273429/cannot-compile-modules-unless-the-module-flag-is-provided)
in Visal Studio 2015 its a bug, but i am in the last Visual Studio Code, and i already create the file tscondif.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "out": "../../built/local/tsc.js",
        "sourceMap": true       
    },
    "files": [
        "core.ts",
        "sys.ts",
        "types.ts",
        "scanner.ts",
        "parser.ts",
        "utilities.ts",
        "binder.ts",
        "checker.ts",
        "emitter.ts",
        "program.ts",
        "commandLineParser.ts",
        "tsc.ts",
        "diagnosticInformationMap.generated.ts"
    ]
}
```

but i still have many errors related to modules compilation and decorators,
how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: I was about to post the exact same question. Have you found the answer yet? Where do we enable the "--module" flag?

Comment: Sorry i didn't find how to fix thoses errors messages

Comment: I seem to have to close my TypeScript file and reopen it for VS Code to use new settings I place in `tsconfig.json` - have you closed and reopened your TypeScript file?

Comment: yes, i did ... i got the same errors